# python function not calling inside another function

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python programming and I need assistance in calling a function inside another function. My first function is:

```
def on_enter_save(event):
    btnSave['background'] = 'gray'
    winsound.PlaySound ('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

def on_leave_save(event):
    btnSave['background'] = '#25219c'
```

My second function is :

```
def New():
    btnSave = tk.Button(main, text="Save", bg="#25219c", fg="white", width=5, height=1, relief="flat", command=save)
    btnSave['font'] = MyFont2
    btnSave.place(x=750, y=1000, anchor=CENTER)
    btnSave.bind("<Enter>", on_enter_save)
    btnSave.bind("<Leave>", on_leave_save)
```

I don't know what is the problem if anyone has a solution?

Comment: You're going to likely need to give much more information than this. What are you expecting to happen, what's going wrong, and what debugging have you done? Also, please try to show a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: You serm to use `btnSave` as global variable. You need to declare it for that to work via `global`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `on_enter_save` instead of `save`

Answer (score 0):

The only function call is the winsound.Playsound function, the remainder is redundant.  As commented elsewhere, you need to provide more information.  However, to answer the question as stated, this is how you do it:

```
    def f1(msg):
        print(msg)
        print("Calling f2")
        f2("Hello from f1")

    def f2(msg):
        print("Starting F2")
        print(msg)

    def main():
        f1("Hello from main")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure of 2 main things:

1. Create the function that you want to call before the function you call it in.
2. Don't forget to call the main function too.

This format works:

```
 def calledFunction():
        print("This function is called in another function!")
    
    
    def function():
        print("This is the first function!")
        calledFunction()
    
    
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support. This solved the issue.